# KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD and device not found in /dev/*

Tags: yocto, bitbake, petalinux

I am using Petalinux, built with Yocto SDK. I want to automatically install my kernel module and make the devices available in `/dev/*`.

With `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD+="modulename"` I can see the appropriate entries in `/etc/modules-load.d/` as well as entries in `/sys/class/misc/**` , but not in `/dev/*`. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Does your kernel module actually create device nodes automatically?

Comment: Fixed Typo. If I understand correctly, I create a miscdevice in my module. Previously it worked fine if I installed it to /etc/modules/, but with the new Yocto structure I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Well, the structure of Yocto has nothing to do with the creation of device nodes. Either your driver does that for you (upon loading / probing), or you had some script that made them earlier. As long as your module has been loaded upon boot, you've got `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD` correctly. If the module gets loaded, but you're not getting any device nodes automatically (and you got that before) you'll need to investigate what has changed in your system. (Versions of kernel and eg mdev/udev etc).

Comment: Thanks, the mdev init.d script changed. Using the previous mdev init.d script automatically creates the device nodes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the structure of Yocto has nothing to do with the creation of device nodes. Either your driver does that for you (upon loading / probing), or you had some script that made them earlier. As long as your module has been loaded upon boot, you've got KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD correctly. If the module gets loaded, but you're not getting any device nodes automatically (and you got that before) you'll need to investigate what has changed in your system. (Versions of kernel and eg mdev/udev etc)